# What are the best event equivalents to setUp and teadDown in PHPUnit?

Tags: php, phpunit

I'd like to extend PHPUnit a little by writing a subscriber. I need to run something right before the test starts and then again after its finished. Basically the equivalent of setUp and tearDown methods but using events. PHPUnit has many [events](https://docs.phpunit.de/en/10.2/events.html) but which of these are the closest?

Comment: "I need to run something right before the test starts and then again after its finished."
But ... that's exactly what setUp and tearDown are there for. Whatever you need to happen before the test starts, you put it in your setUp method and anything that should happen after the test goes in tearDown.